# Error 34;Result is too long in socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets

I am new in socket programming. i want to write a simple client-server program but when i run it i am getting an ("error34: result is too long" )in receive function.i would be grateful if you could help me.what should i do?

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef __WIN32__
# include <winsock2.h>
#else
# include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
#ifdef __WIN32__
# include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <netinet/in.h>
#endif

int main(){
WORD wVersionRequested;
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET intSocket,intRSocket;
struct sockaddr_in recServer,recClient,recSin;
int intErr,intLen,Message;
char charbuffer[256];

  wVersionRequested=MAKEWORD(2,0);
  if(WSAStartup(wVersionRequested,&wsaData)!=0)
  {
   printf("Error on initializing");
   exit(1);
  }

  recServer.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  recServer.sin_family=AF_INET;
  recServer.sin_port=htons(3666);

   intSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
   if(intSocket ==(unsigned) -1){
    printf("\n::Error On Create Socket::%d \n", errno);
     perror("socket");
        exit(1);
  }

intErr=bind(intSocket,(struct sockadd*)&recServer,sizeof(recServer));
    if(intErr == -1){
      printf("\n::Error On the Call bind Function::\n");
        exit(1);
 }

else{
      printf("Waiting for incoming connection");}

for(;;)
{

    intErr=listen(intSocket,SOMAXCONN);
     if(intSocket ==(unsigned) -1){
       printf("\n::Error On the Call listen Function::\n");
          exit(1);
    }

    intLen=sizeof(recClient);
    intErr=accept(intSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&recClient,&intLen);
    if(intSocket== (unsigned) -1){
    printf("\n::Error On Connection::\n");
    exit(1);
    }



      do{
        intErr=recv(intSocket,charbuffer,sizeof(charbuffer),0);
         if(intErr==(unsigned)-1)
        {
        printf("\n::Error On Recev Data:: %d\n" , errno );
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
        }
       }
    while( Message=recv(intSocket,charbuffer,sizeof(charbuffer),0));

      Message=recv(intSocket,charbuffer,sizeof(charbuffer),0);

      Message=send(intRSocket,charbuffer,strlen(charbuffer),0);
          system("pause");



   std::ofstream output_file("Recieved Data.txt", std::ios::out);

            if(!output_file)
    {
        printf("file can not open");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
        output_file << charbuffer;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

}

client code:
Client code:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <errno.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <sys/types.h>
     #ifdef __WIN32__
     # include <winsock2.h>
     #else
     # include <sys/socket.h>
     #endif
     #ifdef __WIN32__
     # include <winsock2.h>
     #else
     #include <netinet/in.h>
     #endif


      int main(){
      WORD wVersionRequested;
      WSADATA wsaData;
      SOCKET intSocket;
      struct sockaddr_in recSin;
      int intErr;
      char charbuffer[256];

        wVersionRequested=MAKEWORD(2,0);
        if(WSAStartup(wVersionRequested,&wsaData)!=0)
       { printf("Error on initializing");
         exit(1);
       }

      recSin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
      recSin.sin_family=AF_INET;
      recSin.sin_port=htons(3666);

        intSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
         if(intSocket == (unsigned)-1){
         printf("\n::Error On Create Socket:: %d \n", intSocket );
          perror("socket");
              exit(1);
         }

     intErr=connect(intSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&recSin,sizeof(recSin));
         if(intErr==-1){
         printf("\n::Error On connecting::\n");

         exit(1);
       }

        memcpy(charbuffer, "HELLO\0", 6);
        intErr=send(intSocket,charbuffer,strlen(charbuffer),0);
          if(intErr==-1)
        {
       printf("\n::Error On Send Data::\n");
       exit(1);
       }
      memset(charbuffer,0,sizeof(charbuffer));


      intErr=recv(intSocket,charbuffer,sizeof(charbuffer),0);
      if(intErr==-1){
      printf("\n::Error On Recev Data::\n");
      exit(1);

   }
      printf("Recived Data,pchrBuffer");
      closesocket(intSocket);
   }
```

Comment: copy+paste the code along with error message

Comment: It would help if you would post the code that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server code you're calling `recv()` on the socket you passed to `listen()` and `accept()`.

`accept()` returns a socket representing the connected client. This is the socket you should pass to `send()` and `recv()`.

Also, your `do/while` loop in the server code is a mess. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks a lot my problem solved. you right i change do-while loop. i'm so thankful